# We are using report 6i , where in we are writing query , then it will be converted to excel , where desired o/p is expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

How to get desired o/p.

- id_bl_freight ,id_bl_details are tables.

---

```
select count(*), bl_number from id_bl_freight,id_bl_details
where bl_refno=blf_refno and bl_number='1504156'
group by bl_number,blf_invoice_no
 order by bl_number
```

o/p of above is

```
col1 col2 
1   1504156
1   1504156
1   1504156
```

but what output is desired,

```
col1 col2 
3    1504156
null 1504156
null 1504156
```

Thank you in advance,

We are using report 6i , where in we are writing query , then it will be converted to excel , where desired o/p is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, Reports Builder 6i is an old piece of software.

Query that does what you want might be

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 1504156 bl_number, 1 blf_invoice_no from dual union all
  4     select 1504156 bl_number, 2 blf_invoice_no from dual union all
  5     select 1504156 bl_number, 3 blf_invoice_no from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 2223334 bl_number, 1 blf_invoice_no from dual union all
  8     select 2223334 bl_number, 2 blf_invoice_no from dual union all
  9     --
 10     select 9988776 bl_number, 1 blf_invoice_no from dual
 11    )
 12  -- query you might be interested in begins here
 13  select case when row_number() over (partition by bl_number order by blf_invoice_no) = 1
 14              then count(*) over (partition by bl_number)
 15              else null
 16         end as cnt,
 17         bl_number
 18  from temp
 19  order by bl_number, cnt;

       CNT  BL_NUMBER
---------- ----------
         3    1504156
              1504156
              1504156
         2    2223334
              2223334
         1    9988776

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**However**, regarding 6i version's *age*, I'm not sure that its engine recognizes analytic functions. If not, but your database does, then create a **view** in the database (which will work), and then use that view in Reports Builder as it'll just display the result.